# Can you use automated end-to-end testing frameworks to perform data entry tasks?

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, karma-runner, e2e-testing

I'm often working in places where legacy enterprise architecture requires staff to often have several browser windows open to different systems in order to manually move data over or check fields in unconnected systems.  It occurred to me that perhaps an automated e2e testing framework could be used to do the same task.  Has anyone heard of anybody approaching automated data-entry in this way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not a e2e framework, but a Web Driver to programmatically control a browser (e2e frameworks are commonly built on top of such drivers). Selenium does the job and can control and major browser since IE 6 and has libs for all major languages.

I have done it, to great success. It is a quick and universal way to transfer data en bulk (I can't think what would prevent you from doing it, since you are actually using a UI), but dirty and can't be left unattended (you still have to oversee the process, because the driver won't pay attention to errors shown, unless you teach it).

Before you do it though, can't you interface with the system in question via direst HTTP requests? You can use a tool like Telerik Fiddler to intercept the calls and analyse them (or work your page from any browser from the last 3-5 year, they all offer debugging tools with network traffic inspection). That would be even quicker, albeit, involves more analysis.

The only situation I can think of, where you couldn't use direct HTTP requests, is if you are dealing with ASP.NET WebForms - since you would have to provide ViewState with request, which is not human readable and often encrypted on top. If that is the case - go for Selenium definitely.

Comment: Note that `protractor` is a wrapper around the javascript selenium webdriver. You can use the `driver` directly via `browser.driver` if needed.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I was thinking it would be great to use protractor but was under the impression that it was written specifically for Angular. I know you can override the Angular dependency but would it perform as well as Selenium on its own?   I am more of a JavaScript developer so would love to work with Protractor for this use case.  I'm hoping it's scalable enough.

Comment: Great, use Node. This page has all the examples to get you started https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver